# Accessing an attribute of a multiprocessing Proxy of a class

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a class that I want to share in a read-only fashion with children processes in a pool, so I prepared a proxy of a class but it didn't work. The following is a simplified example of my problem.

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def b(self):
        print self.a

class MyManager(BaseManager): pass

MyManager.register('test', TestClass)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = MyManager()
    manager.start()
    t = TestClass(1)
    print t.a
    mt = manager.test(2)
    mt.b()
    mt.a
```

When I run this code I get:

```
1
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiprocess_example_stackexchange.py", line 20, in <module>
    mt.a 
AttributeError: 'AutoProxy[test]' object has no attribute 'a'
```

It seems that I cannot access the attribute of a shared object directly via a proxy. Is the only way using a method that gets the attribute, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `Proxy` objects used by `multiprocessing.BaseManager` and its sub-classes normally only expose *methods* from the objects they're referring to, not attributes. Now, there is `multiprocessing.Manager().Namespace`, which provides a `Proxy` sub-class that *does* provide access to attributes, rather than methods. We can create our own `Proxy` type which inherits from that, which enables access to all our attributes, as well as access to our `b` function:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, NamespaceProxy

class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def b(self):
        print self.a

class MyManager(BaseManager): pass

class TestProxy(NamespaceProxy):
    # We need to expose the same __dunder__ methods as NamespaceProxy,
    # in addition to the b method.
    _exposed_ = ('__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__', 'b')

    def b(self):
        callmethod = object.__getattribute__(self, '_callmethod')
        return callmethod('b')

MyManager.register('test', TestClass, TestProxy)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = MyManager()
    manager.start()
    t = TestClass(1)
    print t.a
    mt = manager.test(2)
    print mt.a
    mt.a = 5
    mt.b()
```

Output:

```
1
2
5
```

**Edit:**

If you want to be able to dynamically add methods from your original class to a Proxy class, you can do something like this:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, NamespaceProxy
import inspect

class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def b(self):
        print self.a

class AnotherClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def c(self):
        print self.a

class MyManager(BaseManager): pass

class ProxyBase(NamespaceProxy):
    _exposed_ = ('__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__')

class TestProxy(ProxyBase): pass
class AnotherProxy(ProxyBase): pass


def register_proxy(name, cls, proxy):
    for attr in dir(cls):
        if inspect.ismethod(getattr(cls, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__"):
            proxy._exposed_ += (attr,)
            setattr(proxy, attr, 
                    lambda s: object.__getattribute__(s, '_callmethod')(attr))
    MyManager.register(name, cls, proxy)

register_proxy('test', TestClass, TestProxy)
register_proxy('another', AnotherClass, AnotherProxy)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = MyManager()
    manager.start()
    mt = manager.test(2)
    ma = manager.another(3)
    mt.b()
    ma.c()
    mt.a = 5
    ma.a = 6
    mt.b()
    ma.c()
```

Comment: What if I have dozens of methods and a dozen of attributes? Do I need to write them all in TestProxy class? Or is there a more general solution?

Comment: @selotec I don't have time to actually provide an implementation, but you should be able iterate over all the attributes of your class, and dynamically add any methods found to your Proxy class, and to the `_exposed` variable

Comment: @selotec I updated my answer with an example of how you could do it.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it. It seems that you speak about using inspect module. I already solve my case by writing explicit set_ and get_ methods for each "public" attribute.

Comment: How to pass on arguments ?

Comment: Is NamespaceProxy available for python 3?

Comment: @Diamond: You could easily answer that question yourself.

Answer (score 6):

After spending few hours to reading the source codes, here is the simplest ways to implement the proxy class to expose all attributes and methods:

```py
class TestProxy(NamespaceProxy):
    _exposed_ = tuple(dir(Test))

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        result = super().__getattr__(name)
        if isinstance(result, types.MethodType):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                self._callmethod(name, args)
            return wrapper
        return result

BaseManager.register('Test', Test, TestProxy)

manager = BaseManager()
test = manager.Test()
```

Also, here is an auto proxy method:

```py
def Proxy(target):
    dic = {'types': types}
    exec('''def __getattr__(self, key):
        result = self._callmethod('__getattribute__', (key,))
        if isinstance(result, types.MethodType):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                self._callmethod(key, args)
            return wrapper
        return result''', dic)
    proxyName = target.__name__ + "Proxy"
    ProxyType = type(proxyName, (NamespaceProxy,), dic)
    ProxyType._exposed_ = tuple(dir(target))
    return ProxyType

TestProxy = Proxy(Test)
BaseManager.register('Test', Test, TestProxy)

manager = BaseManager()
test = manager.Test()
```

Comment: You don't need to use `exec()`. Just define a `__getattr__()` function (nested is OK), and the use `dic = {'types': types, '__getattr__': __getattr__}` instead. Also, IMO you should have used `TestClass` instead of `Test` to make your code more like the OP's.

Comment: To illustrate what I mean about avoiding `exec()`, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65466807/355230) to the question [How can I update class members in processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65451457/how-can-i-update-class-members-in-processes) which is based on your auto `Proxy()` function.

Comment: One slight edit: The content of the wrapper function should be `return self._callmethod(key, args, kwargs)`.  Otherwise, this swallows and ignores any keyword arguments.  And it always returns None.  Otherwise, this answer (actually @martineau's minor edit to it in the above link) is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Oh, and I notice that @Charchit-Agarwal also noted the bug below.  cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68123850/1332281

Answer (score 3):

Since I do not have enough reputation to comment, I am posting an answer. The otherwise excellent answer by @shtse8 has a bug. I wanted to point this out since this page is one of the top hits when you search for queries regarding NamespaceProxy  and the said answer has been used by others as [well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65466807).

The problem lies in the below code:

```
class TestProxy(NamespaceProxy):
    _exposed_ = tuple(dir(Test))

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        result = super().__getattr__(name)
        if isinstance(result, types.MethodType):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                self._callmethod(name, args)  # Result not returned
            return wrapper
        return result
```

If you use this class (or the equivalent 'auto proxy' method mentioned in the answer) to create proxy objects, then all functions which are programmed to return a value will always return a NoneType instead (if you access the functions from the proxy). Moreover, they will not pass on any keyword arguments either. This is because in the wrapper the result of the method call use `kwargs` and neither is the call itself being returned. Therefore, we need to pass `kwargs` and put a return in the line `self._callmethod(name, args)`.

The `TestProxy` class should then become:

```
class TestProxy(NamespaceProxy):
    _exposed_ = tuple(dir(Test))

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        result = super().__getattr__(name)
        if isinstance(result, types.MethodType):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                return self._callmethod(name, args, kwargs)  # Note the return here
            return wrapper
        return result
```

The 'auto proxy' function would then become:

```
def Proxy(target):
    dic = {'types': types}
    exec('''def __getattr__(self, key):
        result = self._callmethod('__getattribute__', (key,))
        if isinstance(result, types.MethodType):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                return self._callmethod(key, args, kwargs)
            return wrapper
        return result''', dic)
    proxyName = target.__name__ + "Proxy"
    ProxyType = type(proxyName, (NamespaceProxy,), dic)
    ProxyType._exposed_ = tuple(dir(target))
    return ProxyType
```

Update: Edited code and explanation to pass `kwargs` as well. Check [Viktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68286615/16310741) below

Answer (score 2):

[Charcit's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68123850/16399323) was working for me except I made a small completion/bugfixing. There kwargs cannot be passed to the called methods. So the fixed version:

```
class TestProxy(NamespaceProxy):
    _exposed_ = tuple(dir(Test))

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        result = super().__getattr__(name)
        if isinstance(result, types.MethodType):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                return self._callmethod(name, args, kwargs)  # args and kwargs!
            return wrapper
        return result
```

Didn't test the 'autoproxy' method but this fix should apply there too:

```
def Proxy(target):
    dic = {'types': types}
    exec('''def __getattr__(self, key):
        result = self._callmethod('__getattribute__', (key,))
        if isinstance(result, types.MethodType):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                return self._callmethod(key, args, kwargs)
            return wrapper
        return result''', dic)
    proxyName = target.__name__ + "Proxy"
    ProxyType = type(proxyName, (NamespaceProxy,), dic)
    ProxyType._exposed_ = tuple(dir(target))
    return ProxyType
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a less verbose alternative that I found to work well in practice. Not sure if there are any disadvantages.

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def b(self):
        print self.a

def wrap_test_class(*args, **kwargs):
    obj = TestClass(*args, **kwargs)
    obj.get_a = lambda: obj.a
    return obj

class MyManager(BaseManager): pass

MyManager.register('test', wrap_test_class)
```

This allows you to access `a` by calling `proxy_object.get_a()`

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of passing parameters (example: `__getitem__`) or not (example: `__len__`):

```
class TestProxy(NamespaceProxy):
    _exposed_ = ('__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__','__len__','__getitem__')

    def __len__(self):
        callmethod = object.__getattribute__(self, '_callmethod')
        return callmethod('__len__')
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        callmethod = object.__getattribute__(self, '_callmethod')
        return callmethod('__getitem__',(index,))
```

Answer (score 1):

I was originally using the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63741184/1332281) by @shtse8 (as modified by @Charchit-Agarwal and @Viktor), which mostly worked for me, but it was trying to pickle the methods returned by the `__getattr__` function, which didn't work in some use cases.

So here is another solution which is closer to the implementation of NamespaceProxy, but adds in the public methods the same way AutoProxy does.

```
def MakeProxyWithAttrs(target):
    """ Create a derived NamespaceProxy class for `target`. """

    # This bit follows what multiprocessing.managers.MakeProxy normally does.
    dic = {}
    public_methods = [m for m in dir(target) if m[0] != '_']
    for meth in public_methods:
        exec('''def %s(self, *args, **kwds):
                    return self._callmethod(%r, args, kwds)
             '''%(meth,meth), dic)

    # NamespaceProxy starts with __getattribute__ defined, so subclass from that
    # rather than BaseProxy, as MakeProxy normally does.
    proxy_name = target.__name__ + "_Proxy"
    ProxyType = type(proxy_name, (NamespaceProxy,), dic)

    # Expose all the public methods and also __getattribute__ and __setattr__.
    ProxyType._exposed_ = tuple(public_methods + ['__getattribute__', '__setattr__'])

    return ProxyType

class Manager(multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager): pass

test_proxy = MakeProxyWithAttrs(test_func)
Manager.register('test', test_func, test_proxy)

manager = Manager()
manager.start()

test = manager.test()
```