# Working with pathos multiprocessing tool in Python and

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pathos

I have some code for performing some operations using the pathos extension of the multiprocessing library. My question is how to employ a more complex worker function - in this case named `New_PP`. How should I format the thpool line to handle a dictionary that my worker function requires in order to give me a result. Python defaults dictionaries to global variables, but within the scope of the worker function I get an error related to this dictionary (`access_dict`) not being found, so how can I send in the dictionary or ensure it is available to my worker thread.

```
    Nchunks = 10
    thpool = pathos.multiprocessing.ThreadingPool()
    mppool = pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessingPool()
    Lchunk = int(len(readinfiles) / Nchunks)
    filechunks = chunks(readinfiles, 10)
    for fnames in filechunks:
            files = (open(name, 'r') for name in fnames)
            res = thpool.map(mppool.map, [New_PP]*len(fnames), files)
            print res[0][0]
```

And the worker function:

```
def New_PP(line):
    split_line = line.rstrip()
    if len(split_line) > 1:
      access_dict[4] ....
```

How can the worker function get at `access_dict`?

I have also tried to wrap up my function inside a class as follows:

```
class MAPPP:
    def New_PP(self, line):
        self.mytype = access_dict
        return my_type

    def __init__(self, value_dict):
        self.access_dict = access_dict
```

and:

```
mapp = MAPPP(value_dict)
print mapp.value_dict
res = thpool.map(mppool.map, [mapp.New_PP]*len(fnames), files)
```

However I get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues going on here:

1. your code above has a bunch of errors/typos.
2. when you send off `mapp.New_PP`, it makes a copy of `mapp.New_PP`… so it does not share `access_dict` between instances because those instances are created and destroyed in a different interpreter session on a different processor.

Maybe the following will demonstrate a bit more clearly...

```
>>> class MAPPP(object):
...   access_dict = {}
...   def __init__(self, value_dict):
...     MAPPP.access_dict.update(value_dict)
...     return
...   def New_PP(self, line):
...     MAPPP.access_dict[line] = len(line)
...     return len(line)
... 
>>> 
>>> mapp = MAPPP({})
>>> mapp.access_dict
{}
>>> import pathos
>>> thpool = pathos.multiprocessing.ThreadingPool()
>>> mppool = pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessingPool()
>>> fnames = ['foo.txt', 'bar.txt']
>>> files = (open(name, 'r') for name in fnames)
>>> res = thpool.map(mppool.map, [mapp.New_PP]*len(fnames), files)
>>> res
[[21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 20, 21, 19], [17, 18, 17, 17, 50, 82, 98]]
>>> mapp.access_dict
{}
```

So what happened?  The files were read, line by line… and the lengths of each line were computed… and returned to the main process.  However, the write of the line and length were not added to the instance of `mapp.access_dict` that belongs to `mapp` in the main process… and that's because `mapp` is not *passed* to the other threads and processors… it's copied.  So, it did work… and the lines were added to the relevant copies of the class's dict… but then they were garbage collected when the process/thread did its job and passed the line numbers back through the `map` then shut down.

There is no "super-easy" way to do this in `pathos` or `multiprocessing` right now.  However, you can do it if you use `multiprocessing` and `ctypes`.

You might want to look at working with `multiprocessing` with shared memory and/or proxies:

- [How to synchronize a python dict with multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545961/how-to-synchronize-a-python-dict-with-multiprocessing)
- [How can I share a class between processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612412/how-can-i-share-a-class-between-processes-in-python)
- [How to combine Pool.map with Array (shared memory) in Python multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675766/how-to-combine-pool-map-with-array-shared-memory-in-python-multiprocessing)

As `pathos` author, I plan to make the functionality to do the above more high-level… but don't have a timeline for that at the moment.

Comment: My understanding was that a dictionary behaves as a global variable, so it should be in scope, but isn't in the threads.

Comment: `value_dict` and `access_dict` are used interchangeably?  The code in `MAAP.New_PP` doesn't make sense at all -- `my_type` vs `mytype`, where does `access_dict` come from, etc.  See my code for something that does work… just not sure if that's anything like your intent.

Comment: Oh that's a typo, my bad, they are essentially one and the same dictionary.