# Multiprocessing and dict empty after update [python3]

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary, concurrency, python-multiprocessing

i have one problem with my code in python3 : 
i tried many solutions but still the same result.

```
import pprint
import concurrent
import multiprocessing
from concurrent import futures

class exempleStackOverFlow: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict1={}
        self.headers = {"header1","header2","header3"}

    def fillIn(self,key):
        response = {key:{'first':['1','2','3']}}
        self.dict1.update(response)
        pprint.pprint(response)

e =  exempleStackOverFlow()

def try_my_operation(item):
    try:
        e.fillIn(item)      
    except:
        print('error with item')

executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(2)
futures = [executor.submit(try_my_operation, item) for item in e.headers]
concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
print(e.dict1)
```

**Result**

```
{'header3': {'first': ['1', '2', '3']}}
{'header1': {'first': ['1', '2', '3']}}
{'header2': {'first': ['1', '2', '3']}}
{}
```

**Expected**

```
 {'header3': {'first': ['1', '2', '3']}}
 {'header1': {'first': ['1', '2', '3']}}
 {'header2': {'first': ['1', '2', '3']}}
 {'header1': {'first': ['1', '2', '3']},
'header2': {'first': ['1', '2', '3']},
     'header3': {'first': ['1', '2', '3']}}
```

(or what ever order of headers)

I might not have understood how this is working, i would like some light on my problem please, the dict1 is empty at the end when i enter 
`try_my_operation`.

it does update well without the multiprocessing/concurrent ( like if i do `e.fillIn("headers1"),e.fillIn("headers2")`... and after i can get the dict1 full.

Thank you for any future comments

Comment: You are creating 2 processes on top of the one main process.
Your result is expected from your code. Is the idea to get your current result plus print all three appended together from `self.dict1.update`?

Comment: Thank for your answer, it s just the result from both print to track changes. in the Result my dict returned is empty {} instead of what i would want in the 'expected' which mean `self.dict1 equal to   {'header1': {'first': ['1', '2', '3']},
'header2': {'first': ['1', '2', '3']},
     'header3': {'first': ['1', '2', '3']}}`   instead of self.dict1 equal to {}

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for ThreadPoolExecutor, not ProcessPoolExecutor.

Here I use multithreading (without concurrent) to get your expected output:

```
import pprint
from threading import Thread

class exempleStackOverFlow: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict1={}
        self.headers = ["header1","header2","header3"]

    def fillIn(self,key):
        response = {key:{'first':['1','2','3']}}
        self.dict1.update(response)
        pprint.pprint(response)

def try_my_operation(item):
    try:
        e.fillIn(item)
    except:
        print('error with item')

e =  exempleStackOverFlow()

for i in range(len(e.headers)):
    futures = Thread(target = try_my_operation, args = (e.headers[i],));
    futures.start();
    futures.join();

print(e.dict1)
```

The difference being that `e` in multiprocessing is not a shared object, so `e` does not update between all processes. In multithreading, they share the same variables, so `e` can be updated as expected.

**Edit:**

I'm unfamiliar with concurrent, but I'm sure it has a similar method to sharing types and objects like [multiprocessing does](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) shown [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects) and objects using managers like the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612412/how-can-i-share-a-class-between-processes).

If speed is what you're looking for, definitely go the multiprocessing route and share your object using a manager like the one `from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager`.

Comment: Hello again, thank for the answer it's working now, but i lost all the speed from the previous method ? Any guess ?

Comment: Yep. Threads don't offer speed improvements in python. See my answer's edit.

Comment: yes speed is the only purpose, ok i will look BaseManager ! i 'll return soon to give answer on this post. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

with the Help of @Treyten Care

Need to add to my initial post:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager 

class exempleStackOverFlow: 
        def __init__(self):
            manager = Manager()
            self.dict1 = manager.dict()
```

With this i can get my dict updated.
Thank