# Python multiprocessing Manager with @property objects

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a fairly complex object I need to share access to across processes in Python.  It has a few @property methods/attributes on it which the AutoProxy doesn't seem to process.  How can I expose these through the manager?

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, a):
        self._a = a

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

class FooManager(BaseManager): pass

FooManager.register("Foo", Foo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fmgr = FooManager()
    fmgr.start()
    foo = fmgr.Foo(5)
    # Below causes error
    foo.a
```

And the error I get is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 26, in
>   
>       foo.a AttributeError: 'AutoProxy[Foo]' object has no attribute 'a'

### EDIT

So as mentioned in the comments below, one approach is to also define this:

```
class FooProxy(NamespaceProxy):
    _exposed_ = ('__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__', 'a')
```

And register the Foo object as:

```
FooManager.register("Foo", Foo, FooProxy)
```

While this seems to work fine if anyone knows a more automatic process to incorporate any and all @property objects that would be terrific.

Comment: ive never messed with the managers (tbh i didnt even know there was such a thing ... thats kind of cool .. ) now im somewhat curious and might dig a little deeper, however this answer looks like it might shed *some* light https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499548/accessing-an-attribute-of-a-multiprocessing-proxy-of-a-class

Comment: Yeah I saw that one, I was hoping there was some other way to do it in a more automated fashion instead of explicitly exposing each attribute (there's a good amount of them).  If there isn't some more automatic way then I suppose that's the way to do it for each individual attribute/property.

Comment: or just make them not properties and make them methods and interact with them as methods

Comment: Yes - that would work - issue is the actual implementation is used all over the place by many other classes/functions which assume access to the properties.

Comment: So as @JoranBeasley pointed out from the post mentioned in the first comment, I can create a: FooProxy object and add all the property calls to the _exposed_ attribute.  If anyone knows a more automatic way that's great, otherwise this approach seems to work.