# Using a class decorator to automatically run a method with a child process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-decorators

I was asked to develop a consistent way to run(train, make predictions, etc.) any ML model from the command line. I also need to periodically check the DB for requests related to training, like abort requests. To minimize the effect checking the DB has on training, I want to create a separate process for fetching requests from the DB.

So I created an abstract class `RunnerBaseClass` which requires its child classes to implement `_train()` for each ML model, and it will run `_train()` with `_check_db()` using the multiprocessing module when you call `run()`.

I also want to get rid of the need for the boilerplate

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   ...
```

code, and make argument parsing, creating an instance, and calling the `run()` method done automatically.

So I created a class decorator `@autorun` which calls the `run()` method of the class when the script is run directly from the command line. When run, the decorator successfully calls `run()`, but there seems to be a problem creating a subprocess with the class' method and the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Runner(RunnerBaseClass):
  File "/Users/yongsinp/Downloads/runner_base.py", line 27, in class_decorator
    instance.run()
  File "/Users/yongsinp/Downloads/runner_base.py", line 16, in run
    db_check_process.start()
  File "/Users/yongsinp/miniforge3/envs/py3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/Users/yongsinp/miniforge3/envs/py3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "/Users/yongsinp/miniforge3/envs/py3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 284, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/Users/yongsinp/miniforge3/envs/py3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(process_obj)
  File "/Users/yongsinp/miniforge3/envs/py3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/Users/yongsinp/miniforge3/envs/py3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 47, in _launch
    reduction.dump(process_obj, fp)
  File "/Users/yongsinp/miniforge3/envs/py3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.Runner'>: attribute lookup Runner on __main__ failed
```

Here's a minimal code that can be used to reproduce the error.

runner_base.py:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from multiprocessing import Process


class RunnerBaseClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def _train(self) -> None:
        ...

    def _check_db(self):
        print("Checking DB")

    def run(self) -> None:
        db_check_process = Process(target=self._check_db)

        db_check_process.start()
        self._train()

        db_check_process.join()


def autorun(env_name: str):
    def class_decorator(class_):
        instance = class_()

        if env_name == '__main__':
            instance.run()

        return instance

    return class_decorator
```

run.py:

```
from runner_base import RunnerBaseClass, autorun

@autorun(__name__)
class Runner(RunnerBaseClass):
    def _train(self) -> None:
       print("Training")
```

I have looked up the cause for this error and can simply fix it by not using the decorator, or turning the method into a function.

runner_base.py:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from multiprocessing import Process


class RunnerBaseClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def _train(self) -> None:
        ...

    def run(self) -> None:
        db_check_process = Process(target=check_db)

        db_check_process.start()
        self._train()

        db_check_process.join()


def autorun(env_name: str):
    def class_decorator(class_):
        instance = class_()

        if env_name == '__main__':
            instance.run()

        return instance

    return class_decorator


def check_db():
    print("Checking DB")
```

I can just use the function instead of the method and be done with it, but I don't like the idea of passing configurations and objects for inter-process communication(like `Queue`) to the function which I don't have to when using a method. So, is there a way for me to keep `_check_db()` a method, and use the `@autorun` decorator?

(I am aware of using `dill` and other modules, but I'd like to stick with the builtin ones if possible.)

Comment: I have updated my answer for a working solution to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There might be a couple of misunderstandings here.

> I can just use the function instead of the method and be done with it, but I don't like the idea of passing configurations and an object for communication in between processes to the function which I don't have to when using a method

It's understandable why you might think this, but your logic for using a method rather a function is flawed if you are planning to modify objects of `Runner`, in either the child or the parent processes. When you spawn processes using start method "[spawn](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods)" (the default on Windows and macOS), the child processes don't have access to the parent's memory space. Therefore, if you create an object of `Runner`, and pass it to a process, that process will have a duplicate of that object with a different memory address than the one present in the parent. Any modifications made to these objects will **not** be propagated across processes. Same goes for start method "fork" (default on Unix), the only difference being that it uses [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write), where, rather than on start, the duplicate will only be created if you attempt to modify the object in the child process.

So just keep in mind that sharing objects like you are trying to do only makes sense if you aim to use the objects as **read-only** (like passing configurations and data from one process to another), and don't care about whether the changes made to them are reflected in the other processes. If you also want them to be writable, you can simply use [managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72708828/how-to-create-the-attribute-of-a-class-object-instance-on-multiprocessing-in-pyt/72711246#72711246) mentions. Keep in mind that using managers will negatively impact your code's performance (as communication will require all data to be serialized).

### This brings us to the next question: ***can you even pass complex objects to another process?***

Multiprocessing uses pickle to transfer data from one process to another. This means that any object passed as an argument must be **picklable**. Whether or not pickle can serialize complex objects like instances of `Runner` is then very much dependent on the instance attributes the object has. In your case, the problem isn't with pickling your instance, it's with the fact that **you are attempting to do so when the class `Runner` hasn't even been added to the top-module**. To check this, change your decorator to print whether the class exists in the global attributes before it attempts to create an instance:

```
def autorun(env_name: str):
    def class_decorator(class_):
        print(class_.__name__ in globals())
        instance = class_()

        if env_name == '__main__':
            instance.run()

        return instance

    return class_decorator
```

Output:

```
False
```

*In general*, attributes not defined at the top module are not picklable with `pickle`, and this is why your code fails with a pickling error. Additionally, you also won't be able to use class `ABC`, since that can't be pickled either.

### So what's the solution?

I recommend you to look outside the builtins to achieve what you want, or, like you mentioned, change the method `check_db` into a function. Apart from that, there is also a rather *unintuitive* workaround that you can use.

**Method 1**

If you do decide to use something better, like [multiprocess](https://pypi.org/project/multiprocess/), which uses `dill` rather than pickle, your code will become like this:

```
from multiprocess import Process


class RunnerBaseClass:

    def _train(self) -> None:
        ...

    def _check_db(self):
        print("Checking DB")

    def run(self) -> None:
        db_check_process = Process(target=self._check_db)

        db_check_process.start()
        self._train()

        db_check_process.join()


def autorun(env_name: str):
    def class_decorator(class_):
        instance = class_()

        if env_name == '__main__':
            instance.run()

        return instance

    return class_decorator


@autorun(__name__)
class Runner(RunnerBaseClass):
    def _train(self) -> None:
       print("Training")
```

**Output**

```
Training
Checking DB
```

**Method 2**

The second method relies on you changing the decorator to create an instance of the passed class's parent class instead, and attach it to a child of `Runner`. Consider this code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

    class RunnerBaseClass:

    def _train(self) -> None:
        ...

    def _check_db(self):
        print("Checking DB")

    def run(self) -> None:
        db_check_process = Process(target=self._check_db)

        db_check_process.start()
        self._train()

        db_check_process.join()


def autorun(env_name: str):
    def class_decorator(class_):

        # Create instance of parent class
        instance = class_.__bases__[0]()

        if env_name == '__main__':
            instance.run()

        return instance

    return class_decorator


class Runner(RunnerBaseClass):
    def _train(self) -> None:
        print("Training")


@autorun(__name__)
class RunnerChild(Runner):
    pass
```

Here, we attach the decorator to `RunnerChild`, a child of class `Runner`. The decorator then creates an instance of `RunnerChild`'s parent class and executes `run()`. By doing it in this order, the `Runner` class has already been added to the top-module and can therefore be pickled.

**Output**

```
Training
Checking DB
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The reason for not wanting to use non-builtin modules was that this is supposed to be deployed to servers with various configurations and restrictions (also without internet connection) and adding dependencies could result in a headache for people who maintain and update those servers... and I wanted to keep this as simple as possible. The multiprocess module seems nice, and I'll also look into the other method you suggested!

Comment: I only have two processes and need the child process to tell the parent process about the requests on the DB, so I use Pipe for a unidirectional communication between the child process and the parent process. I just decided to leave that part out since it didn't seem relevant at the time I was composing the question :)

Comment: I just meant that the configurations and the `Pipe` `Connection` objects were instance variables so I wouldn't have to pass them to a method, but I see now why you might think that I was trying to share the state between processes and the fault lies on my end.

Comment: Also, what bugs me is that I don't think pickle has a problem pickling the `check_db()` method because everything works fine when I manually create an instance and call `run()`. It's just that when I use the `@autorun` decorator Python seems to have a problem looking things up from the top-level code environment.

Comment: @YongsinPark, I see. I think I understand your code a bit better now. Earlier, I had reached an erroneous conclusion about why the pickling error was being raised. I have updated my answer to include a correct explanation and a way to do what you are trying to do with minimum overhead (check method 2 in the answer above).

Comment: Thank you! I have just been suspecting the `Runner` class might not have been added to the top-level code environment when the `@autorun` kicks in but was having trouble proving and solving it. I would upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation yet. Hope you have a good one! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but you don't have to use decorators at all or the boilerplate.

After making your class, you can outside of it just write the code to make an object and run the functions, you don't need the if `__name__ == "__main__"` part.

And if you want to run specific functions from the command line, you could use the sys module and get arguments with `sys.argv[1]`. For example, if you wanted to train in one command, then make predictions in another, you could get the value of sys.argv and, using an if statement, check what the value is. If it is for example, "train", you could invoke a train function, or whatever else you need to do.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but what I wanted was to eliminate the need for writing the code that comes after the `if __name__ == '__main__':`, not the line itself. For instance, I would have to parse command-line arguments, create an instance, and call `run()` with the appropriate parameters according to the arguments but that bit of code will be used everywhere so wouldn't it be great if you can simplify that by just adding the `@autorun` decorator to the class? Perhaps I stripped away too much code from the question. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Oh ok, makes sense. Your question is fine, I just misunderstood it. Good luck on your code!